# Android Studio can't open project

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.3

I've recently get update notification of android studio 2.3, after the update it's not opening any project and throwing error:[image]

> [plugin: com.darkklord.gradle.metric.core]

after downgrading and reinstalling i still have this issue, can anyone please help me on this topic ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download latest plugin from here: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9197-android-gradle-metrics--checkstyle

- Install Plugin manually from disk.
- Restart Android Studio (The error will still occur)
- Remove plugin in IDE.
- Restart

You might also uninstall the refrenzed plugins Checkstyle and PMD

Comment: did all above steps but still having the same error

Comment: I am not sure if its the missing part. I deleted caches before. For Windows User--> Android Studio --> system --> caches. Do not forget to make a backup before!

Comment: Sadly google updated a lot of internals in 2.3 android studio which makes it incompatible with the plugin, so it wont work with 2.3 until I update the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your dependency

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need to change name of project manually(look at AndroidStudioProjects folder) that you opened lastly.

After changing name, android studio will show all projects,
open one of them,

in file menu,
click open button,
then open your desire project (or change its name to its previous name)

Answer (score 0):

change build:gradle plugin to:

```
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
```

(in app gradle file)

Answer (score 0):

I made sure that my Gradle version was compatible with my android gradle plug in. In my case  I was using Gradle 6.0.1 and when  I changed my android gradle plug in to version 3.5.3 the problem went away. 
Project Structure----->> Project ------>> Android Gradle plug in version 3.5.3.

[https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/release-notes.html 
[Java 14 and later versions are not yet supported.
 Compatibility Notes
A Java version between 8 and 13 is required to execute Gradle.

Java 6 and 7 can still be used for compilation and forked test execution. Just like Gradle 5.x, any supported version of Java can be used for compile or test.

This version of Gradle is tested with

-------->>>>>>>>Android Gradle Plugin 3.4, 3.5 and 3.6
Kotlin 1.3.21 through 1.3.50
Other versions may or may not work.]]]]

I hope this helps