# Android studio 2.3.0 startup exception

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.3

After upgrading to Android studio v2.3.0 on macOs, every time I try to open any project I get an error

Here's what I'm getting:

[image]

The only thing that helped me resolve this issue is by resetting the Android studio completely [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31228003/1801248) answer helped me doing so but, this is just a temporary solution because after closing the IDE and re-opening it again, same thing happens again.

Is there a solution for this error or should I downgrade?

Comment: May be this link helps you: [plugin: com.darkklord.gradle.metric.core](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42573313/android-studio-cant-open-project/42623779)

Comment: Thanks... it worked